# How I can switch WinAppDriver to another version

Tags: winappdriver

WinAppDriver is shipped with MSI package and it requires admin to install/uninstall it. Although WinAppDriver is already shipped with Microsoft hosted build agents, but I want another version, how I can switch WinAppDriver to another version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [download](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/archive/master.zip) the most recent version from their [github page](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver).
If you need a older version, please check their [release page](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/releases). You will need to click the "assets" toggle in order to see the downloadable files.